# How to know the input / output sockets of a Node, without importing it into the project, with Python?

Tags: python, shader-nodes

How can I know the sockets of a node (for example the BSDF Principled node), without it being used?

Let me explain, I need to know the properties of the BSDF node in particular, to know the sockets of this node, as in the various versions of Blender, the sockets change in number and type (Mainly the inputs have increased in recent years)

So I would like to access these properties when starting Blender, without having to create a material, and without having imported the "Physically" node in the node_tree

I am looking in the Blender API, but I have not found anything and I do not know if it is possible.

I wish I could know about sockets as I normally do like this:

```
inputs = [i for i in bsdf.inputs]
outputs = [o for o in bsdf.outputs]
```

I just want to get the bsdf variable even before importing the BSDF node.

I think there is access somewhere, but I'm not sure.
Something like `bpy.types.ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled` but I don't know where

Comment: AFAICT you can only do this by inspecting the Blender source code and creating a list of nodes by hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show the solution suggested by Marty Foust and scurest:

```py
import bpy
from bpy import context as C, data as D
import json

TEMP_NAME = "Temporary Material"
TEXT_NAME = "JSON data"
prefix = 'ShaderNode'
excluded = (prefix, 'ShaderNodeCustomGroup', 'ShaderNodeTree')

node_names = [n for n in dir(bpy.types) if n.startswith(prefix) and n not in excluded]

# the below line would be useful for Scurest's solution
# node_types = map(lambda n:getattr(bpy.types, n), node_names)

temp_mat = D.materials.get(TEMP_NAME)
if not temp_mat:
    temp_mat = D.materials.new(TEMP_NAME)
    
temp_mat.use_nodes = True
nodes = temp_mat.node_tree.nodes

out = []

for name in node_names:
    nodes.clear()
    n = nodes.new(name)
    socket_to_dict = lambda s: {"type": s.type, "caption": s.label if s.label else s.name}
    inputs = [socket_to_dict(i) for i in n.inputs]
    outputs = [socket_to_dict(o) for o in n.outputs]
    
    result = {"name": name, "inputs": inputs, "outputs": outputs} 
    out.append(result)
    
nodes.clear()
D.materials.remove(temp_mat)
D.texts.new(TEXT_NAME).from_string(json.dumps(out, indent=4))
```

This creates a new Text File with example information in it.

Keep in mind some nodes have various modes with different inputs/outputs. Switching modes will enable/disable those sockets, which then become invisible to the user. Getting all possible options isn't trivial, as those options have different names, e.g. in *Math* node it's `operation`, and in *Voronoi* it's for example `distance` (and that node has more options that alter the number/name of sockets).

Comment: Interesting solution. This means that you can write the json with for example an on_blender_start Handler and write the file only once, then call it when needed. I really hadn't thought about it. Also useful is the advice of sockets, I am aware of this, and I think it is very useful for those who read this answer.

Comment: @NoobCat I'd say generate the file once and attach it to the scripts you use. One for each version if it changes between versions (I think it doesn't change between 3.0 and 3.1 but didn't test).

Comment: I gave the score to you, because it seems to be the most effective, without risking too much on a possible "API change / problem" in Blender.

Answer (score 4):

You can access this with [`input_template`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled.html#bpy.types.ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled.input_template) and [`output_template`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled.html#bpy.types.ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled.output_template)

```
>>> bpy.types.ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled.input_template(0).identifier
'Base Color'
>>> bpy.types.ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled.input_template(0).type
'RGBA'
```

I don't know how to get the number of templates but perhaps you can just loop until you get None

```
node_type = bpy.types.ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled
inputs = []
i = 0
while True:
    tmpl = node_type.input_template(i)
    if tmpl is None: break
    inputs.append(tmpl)
    i += 1
```

---

**edit** As @Chris points out in the comments, this only worked up until 3.0. Starting with 3.1, it doesn't, see https://developer.blender.org/T93932. Quoting from there

> Basically we're migrating to a new API for declaring the sockets of each node which isn't exposed to RNA yet. Internally, the templates have been marked as deprecated for about a decade, no one had made a proper replacement though.
>
> And yeah, the **workaround is probably adding a node of that type temporarily and examining the sockets**.

Comment: if i put your command in the console, i get: >>> bpy.types.ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled.input_template(0).identifier
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'identifier'....what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @Chris I have no idea. It works for me in 2.79 and 3.0.

Comment: you are right. It doesn't work in 3.1 :(