# How to get the property name and its value in ShaderNode?

Tags: python

- 1.For ShaderNodeValToRGB, how can I get color_ramp on the node by Python API suppose I do not know it is ShaderNodeValToRGB? I want to automatically get the ShaderNodeValToRGB and its property color_ramp which can be changed on the node and ignore all other properties.
- 2.Same as above for ShaderNodeTexNoise, how can I get noise_dimensions
  and its value by API? I use
  ShaderNodeTexNoise.rna_type.properties to list all the property
  including noise_dimensions, but I only want to list noise_dimensions
  and its values not including other properties which are not included
  on the node.

Comment: Related: [How to know the input / output sockets of a Node, without importing it into the project, with Python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/254305/how-to-know-the-input-output-sockets-of-a-node-without-importing-it-into-the)

Comment: Thank you! Will test now.~

Answer (score 3):

What I do when I don't know stuff is I create a sample so in this case an object with a material and ColorRamp node, open Python console and use it's Autocomplete function (<kbd>Tab</kbd>) to find out what stuff is available in the API.

So first I find the node and see what else is in it:
[image]

when I see something interesting, I explore that:
[image]

It seems like something called 'elements' might be a list of something so I try to access it's first element:
[image]

After I find that it has color I check it's values and compare it with my node and if I change the second color to red the values of `element[1].color` also change so I found the color ramp:

[image]

You can also try changing stuff from Python Console:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very helpful!